# About semidirect product and faithful actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I need some help with the following question:

We have $H$ acting by automorphisms on $N$, and let $\rho:H\to Aut(N)$ the associated representation by automorphisms.

Suppose that $G=H[N]_{\rho}$ is a semidirect product, and $K=\ker(\rho)$.

Prove that $K\unlhd G$ and  that $G/K$ is also a semidirect product.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

---

Edit: I deleted the part that was unclear (in fact bad formulated). The answers of DonAntonio and user finally solved the question.

Comment: The facct is that I don't even know how to approach this... :s

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Someone with the level to be given this question **must** at least do something: you *have* to know what semidirect product (an exterior one, as in your question) is, how it looks, etc.

Comment: BTW, I think it is more usual to denote the semidirect product as $\;N\rtimes H\;$ or $\;H\ltimes N\;$ , depending on what coordinate in the cartesian product we want the normal subgroup of the product to be represented.

Comment: Well, let's start facing the first question. You already know that $K$ is normal in $H$, because it's the kernel of a morphism (i.e. $\rho$) and that all of it's elements induce the identity on $N$. So...

Comment: Well @GiulioBresciani, $\;K\lhd H\;$ because it is the kernel of a homomorphism. Period. Now, the question is why in fact $\;K\lhd G= N\rtimes H\;$ ...

Comment: As $K\unlhd H$, and $K\cong{1_N}\times K\unlhd {1_N} \times H\unlhd N\times H$, can we deduce that $K\unlhd G$?

Comment: Not so easy, @Mark_Hoffman: in direct products **yes**, but we have here a *semi* direct product ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly:

We use the notation $\;N\rtimes H\;$ , and the operational notation in the semidirect product (=s.p.):

$$(n_1,h_1)(n_2,h_2):=(n_1n_2^{h_1},h_1h_2)\;\;,\;\;n_2^{h_1}:=\rho(h_1)(n_2)$$

So suppose $\;k\in K\le H\iff \rho(k)=\text{Id}_N\;$ . In the s.p. we can denote this element as $\;(1,k)\;$ , and thus we get that

$$(n,h)^{-1}(1,k)(n,h)=(n^{-h^{-1}},h^{-1})(1,k)(n,h):=$$

$$(n^{-h^{-1}},h^{-1})(n^k,kh):=\left(n^{-h^{-1}}(n^k)^{h^{-1}}\,,\,h^{-1}kh\right)$$

Now, obviously $\;h^{-1}kh\in K\;$ since clearly $\;K\lhd H\;$, and in the first coordinate we have (remember that $\;H\;$ acts *by automorphisms* on $\;N\;$!):

$$n^{-h^{-1}}n^{kh^{-1}}=\left(n^{h^{-1}}\right)^{-1}n^{h^{-1}}=1$$

because $\;k\in K=\ker\rho\iff n^k=n\;\;\;\forall\,n\in N\;$ !

The above is, of course, after you already prove you have a semidirect product here, but that's easy and, in fact, some parts above can help you to see this.

Comment: Your explanation was very clear, DonAntonio, thanks!

Now that we have that $K\unlhd G$, how can I see that the quotient $G/K$ is also a semidirect product given by that action $\overline\rho$?

Comment: That @Mark I shall leave to you, but in your text book (which book are you reading?) it must appear, and not only that: as remarked at the end of it, in my answer you can see examples of what the inverse of an element in the s.p. is and how to multiply elements. Use this *knowledge* ...

Comment: I'm not following any book. Just some brief class notes. These kind of exercises have been proposed to us even without presenting a definition of semidirect product... So that's why I was quite lost.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand very well the last part of your question, but for me things look like this:

Take $\bar{\rho}:H/K\to Aut(N)$ defined by $\bar{\rho}(hK)=\rho(h)$. (This is well defined since $K=\ker\rho$.) Then define $\varphi:N\rtimes_{\rho}H\to N\rtimes_{\bar{\rho}}H/K$ by $\varphi(n,h)=(n,hK)$. Now it's easy to prove that $\varphi$ is a surjective group homomorphism and $\ker\varphi=\{1\}\times K$. In particular, $G/K\cong N\rtimes_{\bar{\rho}}H/K$.

Comment: Thanks, user. But this action $\overline{\rho}$ you defined is not faithful, is it?

Comment: If faithful means to have a trivial kernel, then it is.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's ok.

Does the other  $\overline{\rho}$, ($\;\overline{\rho}:H/K\to NK/K,\;\;\overline{\rho}(hK)=\rho(h)K$) give also a structure of semidirect product on $G/K$?

Comment: I have it more clear now. Thanks a lot for your answer, user!